# Check Value in Dict

Tags: elm

Trying to check the value of fruit

```
fruit =
  Dict.fromList
      [ ( 1, { fruitIsGood = False } )
      , ( 2, { fruitIsGood = False } )
      , ( 3, { fruitIsGood = True } )
      ]

whichFruitIsGood : Dict.Dict number { fruitIsGood : Bool } -> String
whichFruitIsGood fruit =
    case get 0 fruit of
        Nothing ->
            Debug.crash "nothing found"

        Just fruit ->
            if fruit.fruitIsGood == True then
                "Apple"
            else
                "I hate Fruit"
```

I don't know how to get at the fruitIsGood prop or whatever you call it in Elm here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `Debug.crash "nothing found"` won't provide to you any useful functionality, what about returning `nothing found` string instead.

Then you just need to fix the errors, which the compiler points out. They are mostly about the variables, which are defined multiple times. Let's rename your first function to `fruits`:

```
fruits =
  Dict.fromList
      [ ( 1, { fruitIsGood = False } )
      , ( 2, { fruitIsGood = False } )
      , ( 3, { fruitIsGood = True } )
      ]
```

And a variable in the second function:

```
whichFruitIsGood : Dict.Dict number { fruitIsGood : Bool } -> String
whichFruitIsGood fruit =
    case get 3 fruit of
        Nothing ->
            "nothing found"

        Just foundFruit ->
            if foundFruit.fruitIsGood == True then
                "Apple"
            else
                "I hate Fruit"
```

Then your code will compile and return `nothing found` as a result.

Here's a small a bit modified [ellie-app example](https://ellie-app.com/3ktTYQdg3ZVa1), which shows the code in action.